# ion-modal called, but not showing

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-fit-modal',
  templateUrl: './fit-modal.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./fit-modal.page.scss'],
})
export class FitModalPage implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(`fit modal page`);
  }

}
```

printed this log( 'fit modal page' ) in chrome debug console
but, not showing modal display

```js
<ion-item (click)="present();">
```

in html

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AgentFitService } from 'src/app/_common/services/agent-fit.service';
import { FitList } from 'src/app/_common/models/fit-list';
import { ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { FitModalPage } from 'src/app/_modal/fit-modal/fit-modal.page';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-fit-info',
  templateUrl: './fit-info.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./fit-info.component.scss']
})
export class FitInfoComponent implements OnInit {
  fitList: FitList = new FitList;

  constructor(private agentFit: AgentFitService, private modalCtrl: ModalController) {
    this.search('');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  search = async( order_id: string ) => {
    const temp = await this.agentFit.getList(order_id);
    this.fitList = <FitList>temp;
    console.log( `fit-info components getList[${temp}]` );
  }

  async present() {
    const modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
      component: FitModalPage
    });
    await modal.present();
  }

}
```

my component that is called modal

and.. module

i can not find error message. my console is clean..

why do not display modal popup ?

but, print to 'fit modal page' log..

@ionic/angular 4.1.1

Comment: you should return the modal.present(); please check answer for details

Comment: Did you import FitModalPageModule in `app.module.ts`?

Comment: so, i meet this error msg

Type FitModalPage is part of the declarations of 2 modules: SettingPageModule and FitModalPageModule! Please consider moving FitModalPage to a higher module that imports SettingPageModule and FitModalPageModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes FitModalPage then import that NgModule in SettingPageModule and FitModalPageModule.

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation you need to return like `return await modal.present();` to show modal.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { ModalPage } from '../modal/modal.page';
@Component({
  selector: 'modal-example',
  templateUrl: 'modal-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal-example.css']
})
export class ModalExample {
  constructor(public modalController: ModalController) {}

  async presentModal() {
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: ModalPage,
      componentProps: { value: 123 }
    });
    return await modal.present();
  }
}
```

> [**Official documentation link**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal)

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 1):

[ SOLVED ]

```
# angular.json
"styles": [
              {
                "input": "src/theme/variables.scss"
              },
              {
                "input": "src/global.scss"
              },
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
```

i'm use to bootstrap ..

styles in angular.json

so, not displayed modal ...

remove bootstrap css line then..

```
# angular.json
"styles": [
              {
                "input": "src/theme/variables.scss"
              },
              {
                "input": "src/global.scss"
              }
            ],
            "scripts": [
            ]
```

that's it. solved..!

yet, i don't know ! why not displayed modal

i just use to bootstrap !!